# How can I open modal when I click on card when I had several cards

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm new to react and getting confused to complete it. 
I had several cards, I used 
**RecommendationCard.js** file and **RecommendationSection. js** file to display the recommendations given by others, the data is stored in **Context.js** file.
When I click any of the card modal should open displaying the content in that card.

Comment: Please do include some code.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, debugging details, and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It needs more info, but I think if I describe one of the solutions, you can solve it by yourself.

You should have an ID for each card. When a user clicks on a card you should add the card's ID to the state.

For example, if you have a state like `openModal=null` should change to ```openModal=12``, then on render function, you should render a modal with data of card with ID of 12.

To set the state on click on each card you can use [curring](https://javascript.info/currying-partials) like bellow

```
<Card
  onClick={handleOpenModal(12)}
  ...
/>
```